# Why i get extra letter between to string when i try to reverse

Tags: c

```
#include<unistd.h>

void reverse(char arr[]){
if(arr[1]!='\0'){
reverse(&arr[1]);
}
write(1,&arr[0],1);
}
int main(){
char text[12] = "this is text";
reverse("try ");
reverse(text);
}
```

Here i am trying to reverse two different strings in two different way. It works pretty good in another editors. But in VScode i get extra letter after the first reverse. What is the reason??

> This is my output : yrtÇtxet si siht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you define a `char[12]` - but you don't leave room for the `\0` that your `reverse` function requires:

```c
char text[12] = "this is text";
```

The result is an array of `char`, not a null terminated string, so your function goes looking for a `\0` out of bounds, which has *undefined behavior* and the garbage output you get is the result.

Either change it to

```c
char text[13] = "this is text";
```

or just let the compiler do the counting for you:

```c
char text[] = "this is text"; // same as: char text[13] = ...;
```

Another option would be to make it a pointer to a string literal:

```c
const char *text = "this is text";
```

---

Sidenote: `<unistd.h>` is a non-standard header which provides the prototype for `write` and other platform specific functions. You don't need that. Just `#include <stdio.h>` and replace `write(1,&arr[0],1);` with a call to a standard function:

```c
putchar(arr[0]);
```